# How to iterate data in an table using *ngFor Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, html-table

I have the following data structure,

```
 [{
    date: '23-09-2024',
    location: [{
                locationName: 'London',
                 locationID: '12',
                ticketIds: [19299298,7383883,585885]
               },
               {
                locationName: 'USA',
                 locationID: '11',
                ticketIds: [1224298,73855553,5555585]
               }]
 },{
    date: '24-09-2024',
    location: [{
                locationName: 'London',
                 locationID: '12',
                ticketIds: [19299298,7383883,585885]
               },
               {
                locationName: 'USA',
                 locationID: '11',
                ticketIds: [124748898,7385444453,5555585]
               }]
 }]
```

I have to iterate data in the table as follows,

[Expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZE1Es.png)

My Implementation:

[Actual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4a84A.png)

Code:

```
  <table>
    <tr *ngFor="let date of toRunData">
      <th>Dates</th>
      <th>{{date.date}}</th>
      <th *ngFor="let loc of date.location">
        <td>{{loc.name}}</td>
         <td>{{loc.ticketIds.length}}</td>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

I know there were errors in the code, as I am learning state now but can anyone please help me to correct the above code to get the expected result. Thanks!!

Comment: `date.Location` should be with lowercase `l`

Comment: This should not be tagged as `reactjs`

Answer (score 0):

To get the required format you can follow the below approach. Keep in mind this is one way of doing it, there is a possibility that you can find other approaches too. Here is a [Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-hlaguu?file=src%2Fmain.ts) for this approach.

1. Extract the dates into an array.
2. Extract the locations into another array along with the tickets count.

> Above arrays must not change the order of the initial dates as in, the
> ticket count should be at the same index for a particular as the date
> is in the first array.

The above mentioned can be achieved with the below code.

```
 <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Dates</th>
      <th *ngFor="let date of dates">{{date}}</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let loc of locations">
      <td>{{loc.locationName}}</td>
      <td *ngFor="let avl of loc.availability">
        <span *ngIf="avl">Tickets Avl: {{avl}}</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

And in you `ts` file use the below code:

```
export class TableComponent implements OnInit {
  toRunData = [
    {
      date: '23-09-2024',
      location: [
        {
          locationName: 'London',
          locationID: '12',
          ticketIds: [19299298, 7383883, 585885, 5858856],
        },
        {
          locationName: 'USA',
          locationID: '11',
          ticketIds: [1224298, 73855553, 5555585],
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      date: '24-09-2024',
      location: [
        {
          locationName: 'London',
          locationID: '12',
          ticketIds: [19299298, 7383883, 585885],
        },
        {
          locationName: 'USA',
          locationID: '11',
          ticketIds: [124748898, 7385444453, 5555585],
        },
      ],
    },
  ];
  locations: any[] = [];
  ngOnInit() {
    this.toRunData.map((date, index) =>
      date.location.forEach((loc: any) => {
        if (!loc.availability) {
          loc.availability = [];
        }
        const ind = this.locations.findIndex(
          (lo) => loc.locationID === lo.locationID
        );
        loc.availability[index] = loc.ticketIds.length;
        if (ind === -1) {
          this.locations.push(loc);
        } else {
          this.locations[ind].availability.push(loc.ticketIds.length);
        }
      })
    );
  }

  get dates() {
    return this.toRunData.map((date) => date.date);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @manish but your code is failing for the following data
toRunData = [
    {
      date: '23-09-2024',
      location: [
        {
          locationName: 'London',
          locationID: '12',
          ticketIds: [19299298, 7383883, 585885, 5858856],
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      date: '24-09-2024',
      location: [
        {
          locationName: 'USA',
          locationID: '11',
          ticketIds: [124748898, 7385444453, 5555585],
        },
      ],
    },
  ];

Comment: it is showing incorrect data according to date

Comment: @rajk yeah seems like i missed a scenario. I have fixed this and updated the answer and the demo.. this also means that you data entries will impact the result so you might have to adapt to other scenarios popping up..